# Custom init.d script gives daemon: not found

Tags: unix, daemon, init.d

On Debian 7 I have a custom `init.d` script to start solr.

I get this error though:

```
Starting solr.../etc/init.d/solr: 18: /etc/init.d/solr: daemon: not found                 
failed. See error code for more information.
```

Answer (score 4):

Fixed with

```
apt-get install daemon
```